# Buttons with push segues on superview of collectionviewcell which has storyboard segue throws error

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I am new to swift and I am stuck with this error. I have a viewController which has a collection view, which has storyboard segue to a viewContoller and two buttons which have push segue to some other viewController. When I am trying to click on those buttons there is a fatal error, which says sender is not a collectionView with the below code.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    if let cell = collectionViewOne.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) 
    {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("showDeals", sender: cell)
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Error indexPath is not on screen: this should never happen.
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    assert(sender as? UICollectionViewCell != nil, "sender is not a collection view")

    if let indexPath = self.collectionViewOne?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UICollectionViewCell) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDeals" {
            let detailVC: DealsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! DealsTableViewController
            detailVC.someCategory = MyIds[indexPath.row]
        }
    } else {
        // Error sender is not a cell or cell is not in collectionView.
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this is the answer, but you should first check if the identifier is showDeals, then do the rest.

Comment: I have checked the identifier and it seems to be the showDeals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add

```
print("sender type : \(sender.dynamicType)")
```

inside your prepareForSegue , don't use assert, but optional chaining to cast the sender variable :

```
if let cell = sender as? UICollectionViewCell
```

instead of :

```
assert(sender as? UICollectionViewCell != nil, "sender is not a collection view")
```

Comment: Your answer is just perfect. Worked fine for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way, I think assert will work if you change != to ==, that's the way it works with assert.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work I just say it's way better to catch the error inside   the else because an assert will not work if he deploy is app but an else will. If he uses an assert the app will crash at (sender as! UICollectionViewCell) but if he doesn't he can simply print a comprehensible error in the else and  the application will not crash

Comment: We know how it works, Venkata doesn't. It was a comment for Venkata ;-)